# Gateway timeout when listing top 100 from either inbox or sent items the last 24 hours

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

We have a multitenant application, that pulls top 100 messages from users inboxes and sent items, once every minute. The code has been working fine, and hasn't been changed the last week, but for the last 24 hours or so, we are getting intermittent gateway timeouts after 30 seconds, across different users and tenants, when pulling the messages from Graph.

Is there anyway to reach out to support, to fix this?

Comment: are you using teh SDK? or in your own code respecting any 429 messages you may be seeing?

Could you share the response header you get which includes the request-ids?

Comment: The code SHOULD respect 429, but it just looks like 504 gateway timeout. I use c# sdk, and here are some headers: "request-id":"0fdf1d14-4d16-4f1c-86b5-9061b75d54dc","client-request-id":"0fdf1d14-4d16-4f1c-86b5-9061b75d54dc","x-ms-ags-diagnostic",{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"004","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_32"}}","Strict-Transport-Security":"max-age=31536000","Cache-Control":"private","Date":"Mon, 20 Apr 2020 15:05:33 GMT

Answer (score 0):

If you reduce the size of the messages you ask in one request and also batch requests to graph you will find that you will not see the 504 gateway time outs. More on batching here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching

Also with your query, what select parameters are you using? Are you using expands or any open extensions as this can put additional load on too.

Comment: It also occurs when I try to download an attachment from a message. For now I’m mitigating it by retrying the request several times with an exponential back off, but it still fails sometimes. Batching would be nice, but it’s not supported in c# sdk yet, and the requests I’m making, rarely fits batching